# How do make REST API call from React without passing through browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, axios

I am making a REST API call from my React application and am running into the following problem:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '[API LOCATION]' from origin '[APPLICATION LOCATION]' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How can I make the REST API call from my react client without the browser interfering? Where do I move the code?

Comment: in your api you correctly setup cors, you need to do more research this issue (tip google the error message) has been asked and answered thousands of times [*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Access+to+XMLHttpRequest+at+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Generally, because of security reasons, you cannot send request from webpage of one domain to another domain unless the requested resource (API LOCATION in your case) has explicitly allowed this. As Lawrence replied, try to look for CORS, or another solution, do the request from your server, not from client.

Comment: @Fide Ok how do I request from the server vs. the client? I have tried all the cors solutions none of them work.

Comment: Can you post the code, which you use for making the request and APi you're using?

Comment: See my answer I have solved this using Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by calling a Google Firebase function (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) from my React client. The Firebase function makes the REST API call and then returns the result back to the React client.